# for loop python the last value is not added in the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

The last value is not added in the tab.
So i create a program to test if a string is contains on other string. it works but the last value is not take in care.
result:

```
result: ['testing', 'toto', 'trete'] 
what expected: ['testing', 'toto', 'trete','apoi']

str= ("""test
testing
toto
trete
apoi""")

tab = str.splitlines()
tabmot = []

mot = ""
for i in range(len(tab)):
  print(int(tab[i])
  if mot in tab[i]:
    mot = tab[i]
  else:
    if mot != "":
        tabmot.append(mot)
    elif tab[i] == tab[-1]:
        tabmot.append(tab[i])
    mot = tab[i]
```

Comment: It is still difficult to understand. Can you please add expected output or elaborate on given example?

Comment: i've added an example,

Comment: doesn't help. so looks like it's tabmot that is the output you need. are you looking for words that are stems like test and testing and so want to keep testing only in the final list?

Comment: Isn't `"""test
testing
toto
trete
apoi""".split('\n') ` (newlines included, even though they are automatically removed from the comment) doing just what you want? Anyway, don't ever use python reserved keywords like `str` as variable names.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: @JHWOOD closing brace of `print` is missing also.

Comment: Rename your variable `str` to `string` then just use `tabmot = [item for item in string.split() if item]`. That should be job done, no need for this for loop. Or are you asking about `test` being a substring of `testing`? In which case, what is the rule for dropping `test` for `testing`?

Comment: `if mot in tab[i]` ? Isn't `tab[i]` itself string? The question is still difficult to understand.

Comment: The only time you are adding to tabmot is with `tabmot.append(mot)` the other `elif` never gets executed. Now, since the only way to add is with `mot` when `i is 4`, then, `mot` value is second last item since, mot is set to tab[i] in previous loop. So, final item will not get added.

Comment: @JHWOOD the problem seems to be on `range` as @Ahtisham pointed out. I'd suggest using a debugger to find such problem, it will make you faster on finding issues in your code. https://docs.python.org/3/library/debug.html Best wishes!

Comment: @JHWOOD How does your program even compile ? `print ( int ( tab [ i ] ) )` is not correct it should be `print ( tab [ i ] )`. If you make the required change then it works. It displays all the values if make the required change.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to create a new list of unique strings from a test string. If that is your intention then this code won´t work. If that is not your intention then see the solution at the end of this post otherwise continue reading.

'mot' stores the previous iteration then you compare with the next element in the 'tab' list. Now suppose, if your input string is ¨test toto testing trete apoi" then you are not comparing 'test' with 'testing'. Your code will result ['test', 'toto' , 'testing', 'trete', 'apoi']. Therefore, it doesn't work the way it should. A basic solution can be achieved with the help of two loops, like this:

```
str= ("""test testing toto trete apoi""")
tab = str.split()
tabmot = []
mot = ""
for i in range(len(tab)):
   mot = tab[i]
   for j in range(i+1, len(tab)-1):
       if(mot in tab[j]):
          if(len(mot) < len(tab[j])):
             mot = tab[j]
   if(mot not in tabmot):
      tabmot.append(mot)
print(tabmot)
```

The solution of your post can be achieved this way:

```
tab = str.split()
tabmot = []
mot = tab[0]
for i in range(1,len(tab)):    
  if mot in tab[i]:
    mot = tab[i]
    tabmot.append(mot)
  else:
    tabmot.append(tab[i])
  mot = tab[i]
print(tabmot)
```

Hope, it'll help!

p.s: btw, you can make it more pythonic.